# Socialite refresh tokens

Tags: laravel, token, laravel-socialite

I'm building a Laravel application where I need a user to be able to connect social channels, such as Twitter, Twitch, YouTube etc. I don't need them to be able to login with these medias, but connect them, so I my application can get access token to retrieve information from their social channels.

I started working on connecting Twitch using Socialite, but I noticed their token expires and that I'm receiving a refresh_token as well.

I followed Socialites advice regarding handling invalid tokens, rather than keeping an eye on when it expires. The issue I ran into though is.. How do I refresh the token with socialite? I don't seem to be able to find a method, where I can get a new token from the refresh_token.

Can anyone tell me if this is even build into Socialite or if I have to build it myself or even use something else than Socialite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refreshing tokens is not up to Laravel Socialite.

This is something you do on the authorization server.

In case of Twitch, see: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/refresh-tokens/

Every [Socialite Provider](https://socialiteproviders.netlify.app/) has its own endpoints. But they all should follow the [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6)

In Laravel, you can use Guzzle like so:

```php
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type'    => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => '<your refresh token>',
        'client_id'     => '<your client ID>',
        'client_secret' => '<your client secret>',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

P.s. After a quick look, it seems you can retrieve this URL dynamically using [the getAuthUrl() method in \SocialiteProviders\Twitch\Provider](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Twitch/blob/master/Provider.php#L27), but this is not in the [Contract](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/4.0/src/Contracts/Provider.php)...

Comment: Ah okay. Would have been handy if Socialite had it though. something like Socialite::driver('twitch')->refreshToken($storedRefreshToken) and the response gave you the new token and expire_at

Comment: If you ask me, both Laravel Passport and Laravel Socialite are wrong interpreted uses of OAuth2 and OpenID Connect.

Comment: Yeah. I mean for login, sure it'll work. But for what I need, it feels like half of the solution only.

Comment: Agree with @JesperAndersen , it's Socialite didn't cover in full circle. It's really bother me regarding this issues.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a `refreshToken()` method you can extend the Provider class and add something along the lines of this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Socialite\SomeProvider;

use SocialiteProviders\SomeProvider\Provider as SomeProviderProvider;

class Provider extends SomeProviderProvider
{
    public function refreshToken($refreshToken)
    {
        $response = $this->getHttpClient()->post(
            $this->getTokenUrl(),
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                ],
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
                    'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
                    'client_id' => $this->clientId,
                    'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
                ],
            ]
        );

        return json_decode($response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```php
Socialite::driver('someprovider')->refreshToken($refresh_token);
```

Comment: where i have to put this code in laravel v10?